# Emacsclient choosing the wrong emacs

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs

I have Emacs running in deamon mode at `/usr/bin/emacs --daemon`

I have been told to start emacs as client I can type `emacsclient -c -a "" $*`

However, that command starts up a new version of the GUI emacs.

I am on Ubuntu and have both the GUI and non-GUI version of emacs installed but when I run that command I only want to connect to the non-GUI emacs daemon I have running.

I can get to this by typing `emacs -nw` but I use `emacsclient -c -a "" $*` so that any time a program opens with the default EDITOR (like a git commit message) it too opens in the emacs daemon.

How can I prevent the GUI emacs from opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace -c with -t. The "c" is for "create-frame". "t" is for "tty". See "man emacsclient" or https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html